# Handling image uploads in parse.com Cloudcode

Tags: image, parse-platform, hosting

I am trying to handle file uploads for a web app through cloud code.I am facing the following issues

1. We cant add third party middle ware such as busboy to parse
2. Express' built in function such as req.files doesn't seem to work with the body parser parse.com provides.
3. I don't want to expose my app key in the client code.

I wanted to know if there is any other way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Parse Cloud is not a Node environment so it is not a surprise that it does not support nmp modules.
2. The middleware Parse provides for express.js does not support file uploads. Instead you need to send the file contents as base64 to your endpoint and create the Parse.File object from this data. [more info here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/580237355440112)
3. Your app and client keys(except for master key) are **PUBLIC INFORMATION** and NOT secrets. This is clearly mentioned in the documentation by Parse and you cannot hide them at all. Use CLPs, ACLs and Cloud code to protect your data from unauthorised access.